# Every second row printed from mysql should be colored

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I have a contact form at my wordpress site, which it's data to mysql and also sends it with mail. I'm currently working on a simple wep app that simply reads the data from the database and prints it. To make it easier to read on mobile, I want that every second row printed from the database would be gray and every second white. I tried this but failed miserably, as you can see from the code. So I want it to look this: 
http://i49.tinypic.com/20fbvdi.png
And here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Yhteydenottopyynnöt</title>
<style>
body{width:100%;}
.anotherrow{background-color:#f1f;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_contactform");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th style='width:10%;'>ID</th>
<th style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'>Nimi</th>
<th style='width:10%;'>Puhelin</th>
<th style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'>Sposti</th>
<th style='width:40%;'>Viesti</th>
<th style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'>P&auml;iv&auml;</th>
<th style='10%;'>IP</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'>" . $row['Nimi'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;'>" . $row['Puhelin'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'><a href='mailto:" . $row['Email'] . "'>" . $row['Email'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td style='width:40%;'>" . $row['Viesti'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;'>" . $row['IP'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please don't get nightmares from the code, it's valid enough for me, and I'm the only one using the web app :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not take the more modern approach and use a CSS3 selector?

```
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #f1f; }
```

See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38) and [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) for the compatibility statuses.

Comment: Like I said, I will be the only one using it, and so on. And my phone's browser supports it, so it's perfect for me.

Answer (score 5):

Create an iteration counter before your while.

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Then if `$i` is even, apply one color, if it's odd, apply the over one.

```
if ($i % 2 == 0) {
  echo "<tr class='firstColor'>";
} else {
  echo "<tr class='secondColor'>";
}
```

Iterator your variable before the `while` ends. `$i++`

Comment: Just use `if($i++ % 2){}` - That way it will increment itself after the comparison and you don't need the `$i++` at the end of the loop

Answer (score 2):

try this ;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Yhteydenottopyynnöt</title>
<style>
body{width:100%;}
.anotherrow{background-color:#f1f;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_contactform");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th style='width:10%;'>ID</th>
<th style='width:10%;'>Nimi</th>
<th style='width:10%;'>Puhelin</th>
<th style='width:10%;'>Sposti</th>
<th style='width:40%;'>Viesti</th>
<th style='width:10%;'>P&auml;iv&auml;</th>
<th style='10%;'>IP</th>
</tr>";

$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr".((($count%2) == 0)?"":" class='anotherrow'").">";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'>" . $row['Nimi'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;'>" . $row['Puhelin'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'><a href='mailto:" . $row['Email'] . "'>" . $row['Email'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td style='width:40%;'>" . $row['Viesti'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;' class='anotherrow'>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='width:10%;'>" . $row['IP'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
$count++;
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't color the right ones. I need to color every second horizontal line. That colored every second column :D

Comment: Nop :) <tr> are lines, not columns :) I make an edit to start color at second row.

Comment: Almost. Now every second line is colored, and every seconds line every second column is colored, if I explain it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to this would be to make 2 simple CSS classes for Odd and Even Values. and define separate background colours in each of them. Then use the following piece of code to get your work done:

```
$j=0;
if(!($j%2)) {
            $cssClass = 'odd';
         } else {
            $cssClass = 'even';
         }
         $j++;

<tr class=<?php echo $cssClass; ?> > Data </tr>
```

Sort of like this.